# Set a default sort column for a JTable in swing

Tags: java, swing

In swing, you are able to click on the column headers to sort by that column. Is there a way to have one selected by default, without having to manually press it?

Comment: Use a table row sorter as per the [relevant tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am already able to sort the table, I am just wondering if it is possible to set a default column to be sorted.

Comment: The duplicate Q&A shows how to do this using a row sorter as does the tutorial.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't see that the first time I glanced over it. Thanks!